# How to run a web application from the command line in Windows 10?

Tags: asp.net, iis, command-line

I've built a web application (i.e., it's got .aspx pages and .dlls, but no .exe) in VS2017. I need to be able to invoke this application on my local machine from the command line. Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried

```
explorer http://localhost:59135/OAuth2Manager.aspx
```

But I get an error page saying "This site can't be reached". (If I run the solution from Visual Studio, it comes up with no problem.)

Comment: When you hit run in Visual Studio, it compiles your application and deploys it in an isolated version of IIS Express, so you can view and interact with your application within a web browser...the best thing that you can do, is install the full version of IIS in your machine, and deploy the Release version of your site, using the Publish menu....you have toons of documentation on line about how to do that, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Comment: To elaborate: "The site can't be reached" because your server isn't running. Run it in visual studio, and, while it's running, issue your command from the command line. Otherwise, use IIS or IIS Express as @Hackerman suggests.

Comment: You need two commands. 1) launch IIS Express and load your web app, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line 2) launch a web browser to access the proper URL.

Answer (score 0):

Create site in IIS. Right click it then edit bindings. Use this settings for local use:

```
type: "http"
Host Name: "YourName.local"
Port: 80
IP Address: *
```

Also you will need to modify your hosts file to point to your site to the correct address. 
Go to

> Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

and add: "YourIP"  "YourName.local" or use local host IP for example:

```
127.0.0.1       mysite.local
```